# Looking for API providing accurate timezone data

Tags: api, time

I'm looking for an API providing accurate timezone data.

Thus far managed to find [earthtools api](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone) but daylight saving time info isn't very accurate.

I need to lookup by latitude/longitude or as an alternative (either one or the other is fine) based on `<city,country>`

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is a question more suited to researching/asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Check out The Google Time Zone API. It provides timezone info based on lat/lon.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/

Answer (score 0):

See this question and answer on stackoverflow for an exhaustive list of options:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates